# Graphing a Second-Degree Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: An ellipse]EX 1.  Graphing a second-degree equation

Solve for Y, and use a function grapher to graph:
 9x^2 + 16y^2 -18x + 64y - 71 =0.

SOLUTION
Step 1.Rearranging terms yields the equation:
 Y=16y^2 + 64y + (9x^2 -18x-71) = 0.

Step 2. The quadratic formula gives us:
Y= -64 plus/minus Radical(64^2 -4(16)(9x^2 -18x-71)/2(16).
 = -8 plus/minus **3**Radical(-x^2 +2x +15)/4.
 = -2 plus/minus(3/4)Radical(-x^2 + 2x +15).

Step 3. Let Y1= -2 + 0.75 Radical(-x^2 + 2x + 15) and 
            Y2= -2 - 0.75 Radical(-x^2 + 2x + 15), and graph the two equations in the same viewing window, as shown in Figure 8.32. 
 The combined figure appears to be an **ellipse**.

Question:  In Step 2, Where does the number 3 that multiplies the three term radical come from?  Is this 3 the square root of 9 that was factored out of inside the radical?  Wonder if someone knows the answer.  Where does this 3 comes from.  Thank you.

Comment: You should use Markdown and Latex to format your question and mathematical formulas.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the part you are asking about?:

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{64^2-4(16)(9x^2-18x-71)} &= \sqrt{64(64-(9x^2-18x-71))}\\
&=8\sqrt{-9x^2+18x+135}\\
&=8\sqrt{9(-x^2+2x+15)}\\
&=8\cdot 3\sqrt{-x^2+2x+15}
\end{align}$$

Does that make it clear how that calculation works? You're right; there's a $9$ being factored out under the radical.